# Query one field with multiple values in elasticsearch nest

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a combination of two queries with Elasticsearch and nest, the first one is a full-text search for a specific term and the second one is to filter or query another field which is file-path but it should be for many files paths and the path could be part or full path, I can query one file-path but I couldn't manage to do it for many file paths, any suggestion?

```
Search<SearchResults>(s => s
                            .Query(q => q
                            .Match(m => m.Field(f => f.Description).Query("Search_term"))
                             && q
                            .Prefix(t => t.Field(f => f.FilePath).Value("file_Path"))
                            )
                            );
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more details if you want anyone to help you.

Comment: I guess you want to select only one field value when it has many.
I don't think elasticsearch supports that. Maybe with scripted fields, but it can be inefficient

Answer (score 0):

For searching for more than one path you can use bool Query in elasticsearch and then use Should Occur to search like logical OR, so you code should look like this:

```
Search<SearchResults>(s => s
                            .Query(q => q.
                             Bool(b => b
                                .Should(
                                    bs => bs.Wildcard(p => p.FilePath, "*file_Pathfile_Path*"),
                                    bs => bs.Wildcard(p => p.FilePath, "*file_Pathfile_Path*"),
....
                                ))
                                && q.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.description).Query("Search_term")
                            )));
```

Also you should use WildCard Query to get result for paths that could be part or full path. For more information check ES offical documentation about WildQuery and Bool Query below:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply but do you think I can use full-text search for file paths instead!

Comment: @m.alahdab it depends on you Analyzer settings for FilePath field.